# how to pass object on Spring's REST Template using get

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using a Spring REST template to pull data using `POST` and everything is working fine.

```
ResponseEntity<MyObject> resp= restTemplate.postForEntity("url", inputParam, MyObject.class);
```

But now since I am not doing any `POST` operation, I want to change it to `GET`. I can do this by adding all input params as url parameters and do:

```
ResponseEntity<MyObject> resp= restTemplate.getForEntity("url",MyObject.class);
```

But the problem is, `inputParam` has alot of parameters, so preparing the url manually is not the best solution.  Also `GET` requests have length restrictions.

Is there any other better solution for handling this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your second line should say `getForEntity()`.

Secondly, there are numerous URL builder class options if you google around (including ones from Spring).  So, I would use a URL building class to prepare the URL rather than manually doing it yourself which can get messy.

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder
- https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

**Length Restriction**

There's a good SO entry here noting length restrictions of common browsers; so if its going through a browser then I'd stick to POST if you're potentially over the 2000 lower limit they suggest.

Technically there shouldn't be a limit according to https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/get7#myths.

I think on a lot of back-end technologies there is no limit.  So, if this is API-only and not going through a browser (like back-end to back-end) then you may be able to ignore those limits.  I'd recommend looking into that specifically though and testing it with your back-end.

**UniRest**

Also, as a personal recommendation, I have found UniRest to be an amazingly useful REST client which makes most of my code much cleaner :).  If you have time, maybe try giving that a shot.

http://unirest.io/java.html

Comment: but still i have to do .queryParam("param1", param1Val) for all params. I don't want to do that for my 20 parameters. Is there a cleaner way to do this?